# How incremental manual RDS snapshot work?

Tags: amazon-rds

I am trying to understand how RDS incremental snapshot work.

Let say I have an RDS instance created 3 years ago, and for audit requirement, I need to keep weekly backup for 5 years. I will name here my snapshot starting from W1 being the inital full snapshot to Wn.

I understand that the initial snapshot contains is full, and next snapshots are incremental.

I understand also that while they are incremental, there is some kind of "squash" mechanism. Meaning if I have snapshot W1, W2, W3, W4, I can delete W2 and W3, but the created data in  W2 and W3 will not be lost as they will be "copied" in W4.  If the data modified in W2 was  modified in W3 or W4, I would have however lost the temporary value.

**Does this process work if I have archive my Snapshot in Glacier?**

**Now, how restoring instance from manual snapshot work? If I want to restore W40 for example, will it go over W1, W2, ... W39, W40 ?**

**If yes, can I force snapshot to be full? For example once a year, I want a full snapshot of my db, then subsequent snapshot will be incremental over the latest full one.**